# What is the definition of the error code 2154 for Chromecast?

Tags: android, chromecast

After successfully connecting then disconnecting an Android phone from Chromecast, my class' `CastSessionManagerListener.onSessionEnded(session: CastSession, error: Int)` returns `error` as `2154`, and `CastStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(error)` returns `unknown status code: 2154`. The error code is not documented and it's coming from the Chromecast library. I'd like to know what the cause is or if I can safely ignore it.

Comment: Hi @clever_trevor I am also getting same issue & same error code. can I know what have you done to resolve this issue.